# Can I fetch data from a json that is in dropbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native, dropbox

The goal is to store json files on an external server. I'm going to fetch data and show in my react native app. The files won't be adjusted often. It's a static data.

The first thing that came to mind is to keep those json files on some file hosting. But I was trying to explore the option of doing the same thing with dropbox.

The get_metadata request `https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_metadata` only provides metadata (obviously).

`get_preview` also won't give me what I need.

Is there a way to store json files in dropbox and read them with react native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, according to documentation at https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download, you can download a file with:

`https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download`

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Thanks